# Rails table view representation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view

I'm trying to build the following table view:

```
+----------+Actor 1+Actor 2+Actor 3+
+ REQ 1    +   X   +       +    X  +
+ REQ 2    +       +   X   +    X  +
+ REQ 3    +   X   +   X   +    X  +
+ REQ 4    +       +       +       +
+----------------------------------+
```

I currently have the following code (not sure about the way to build it though):

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <% @project.actors.order('name').uniq.each do |actor| %>
      <th><%= actor.name %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% @project.requirements.order('position').each do |req, actors| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= req.name_for_display %></td>
      <% actors.sort_by{|a| a.name}.each do |actor| %>
        <td><%= actor.name %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Exception raised: `` undefined method `sort_by' for nil:NilClass ``

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `actors` is nil - that block argument isn't going to set it to anything, it just sets `req` to the Requirement. Not sure how your data models look, but you probably need to extract the actors data from the Requirement.

Comment: Actors are related to `ActorsRequirements` table. Not sure how to extract and render properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved: here is the working code**

**In controller**

```
def method_name
  @project = Project.includes(:requirements => [:actors]).find(params[:id])
  @actors = @project.actors.index_by(&:id)
end
```

**In view**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <% @actors.values.each do |actor| %>
      <th><%= actor.name.titleize %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>

  <% @project.requirements.order('position').each do |requirement, actors| %>
    <% hash = requirement.actors.index_by(&:id) %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to requirement.name_for_display, project_requirement_path(@project, requirement) %></td>
      <% @actors.keys.each do |id| %>
        <td><%= hash[id].present? ? "X" : nil %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```